# how to update 2 content types at once?

Tags: drupal, content-type, cck

i use content_profile and i altered some of other content type cck fields from other module, when user submits the combined form how do i make it to update the 2 content type fields?
for example:
i got content type named "auction_items" and other content type named "auction_item_value" 
in the content type "items" i got fields like "item name" , "brought before X days" etc... and in "item_value" i got fields like "this ad sale price"  etc..
(its just for example) 
i want that when user do new node for auction_items it will get also the fields of the node "auction_item_value , and once he submit it it will update two of the nodes

hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

You could either code your own module and implement the hook_nodeapi to do your processing or use the Rules module which enables many operations which could involve loading related nodes and updating fields. Check drupal.org for documentation on either approach.